# Using php in Form Action

Tags: php, forms, echo

here is my html code:

```
      form action="add_answer.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" form method="post" class="login">
```

The issue is that it directs me to the link: `xxxxxx/add_answer.php?id=%3C?echo%20$id?%3E`

The problem with that link is that it inserts the php code instead of echoing the variables value. Why is this happening?

Note: It does not actually have `xxxxx` in the link, I replaced the beginning part of the link sine it disallowed me to insert localserver into the link.

Comment: Assuming you saved this as an html file?

Comment: Does your PHP file have the `.php` extension? And have you confirmed your web server runs PHP?

Comment: It is a .php file and yes my web server definitely runs php files.

Comment: Can you provide the pages full HTML code? From what I understand you don't need to use <?php echo $id; ?> if you have an input section. It should look more like <form action='add_answer.php' method='post'> and the input <input type='text' name='id'>

Comment: You should look into what is urlencoding your PHP tags.

Comment: Possible he is just doing  `echo '<form action ......';`in which case, the `<?php` stuff would be taken as a literal.  The browser redirect would then handle the conversion of the URL encoding of the invalid characters. This question needs more code preceding and after what was posted to figure a workable solution. Until then, all answers can only be speculative.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do:

```
 <form action="add_answer.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" form method="post" class="login">
```

Do do:

```
 <form action="add_answer.php" method="post" class="login">
   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id;?>' />
```

You should not include parameters in the action itself, but in the form.  If you are echoing the line (a possible reason your PHP tag was not being parsed), do it like:

```
 echo "<form action='add_answer.php' method='post' class='login'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$id}' />";
```